# How to give a user ionice level permission?

Tags: linux, unix, user-permissions, nice

To change hardlimit for nice I can modify /etc/security/limits.conf

```
user - nice -11
```

But how can I do same thing for ionice

```
 ionice -c 1 -p 31828
```

I am getting error

```
ionice: ioprio_set failed: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: I have the same problem; I have 2 machines, in one I can do that and on the other one I can't. The difference is that one is running linux 2.6.18, the other has 3.0.0. Maybe you can't do that in older kernels...

Answer (score -3):

This error (`EPERM`) indicates that you don't have sufficient privileges to perform that operation.  `ioprio_set()`:

> An unprivileged process may only set the I/O
>   priority of a process whose real UID matches the real or effective UID
>   of the calling process. A process which has the CAP_SYS_NICE
>   capability can change the priority of any process.

So, either become the superuser (use `sudo`), or use `ionice` on one of your own processes.

Comment: that process is owned by same user who is running ionice commnad.